# How to train multiple forms of the same query in R-n-R, instead uploading variation of the query & training it?

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

As I understand that in retrieve and rank we need to upload documents followed with questions for training purpose.
- So, like in Watson Conversation we have entities and synonyms that can be added as a dictionary. Do we have a similar feature in R-n-R wherein we can create a library of words for synonym, that can be mapped to a single value. say, savings account can be asked by user as savings acct, savings ac, savings a/c etc.
Right now this is being achieved by uploading variations of the same questions & ranked in task section.
how to open savings acct?, how to open savings ac?, how to open

Is there other ways of doing this, to make it more refined to capture all types of entities/variations asked by user?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of synonyms while creating a collection. This will help retrieve and rank understand that these words are of same meaning. And, these synonyms can be created as groups.